# Log4j.properties not producing timestamp

Tags: java, log4j

I am new to using Apache's Log4J and am trying to be able to produce a timestamp with every bit of Logging it does on a program I am building. However, when I run the program in Eclipse, Log4j is only producing the message I have in my code (without the timestamp). I am thinking it has something to do with how I have my Log4j.properties file set up:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file
log4j.rootLogger=WARNING, file

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=/home/ryan/workspace/wheel/src/main/resources/logging/application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Whenever I try something like this in my code:

`logger.info("Connecting to Server")`

This is what I see in my log file:

`Connecting to Server`

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: i am guessing that you can see the timestamp on your console but not in the log file. correct?

Comment: Good call on that one! I should have known lol :)

Comment: :) happens all the time. also, please accept the answer.

Comment: Will be doing so when SOF allows me to

Comment: cool! Thanks. all the best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is incorrect

```
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

it should be

```
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Comment: Site the difference? - Difference is in property name instead of "stdout" use "file"